# Timeshift not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: backup

Installed from add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa  - worked after installed. Scheduled backups. Did backups. Then I simply closed it and cannot open anymore. I rebooted the computer and still the same. I can see it run as "timeshift-launcher" in System Monitor but cannot see it open anywhere. If I remove it and reinstall it will work again, until I close it and then won't work any longer.

**UPDATE**: It seems to work now (did nothing) - just click to it via Gnome apps and opened. So that's weird. Will report here if I find anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure out if I restart Gnome Shell (Alt then r then Enter) it works again. So take that as a solution for now.